# Saving HTML to file

Tags: javascript, jquery, save

I have taken a look at the example from https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

```
    <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Result will save a `hello world.txt` with `Hello, World!` in the text file. Is it however, possible to save a whole HTML page (page has HTML, JS, CSS) instead of text to `helloworld.html`? I couldn't find any examples of this, or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: document.html() or something like this?

Comment: @realUser404 Tried something like that. Even tried including all the #divs, that's why I thought I might be using the wrong API for what I want. Or maybe I'm missing a keyword in the Blob that's obvious for others.

Comment: @FelixKling I have the `hello world.html` part. Is there a way to add the whole HTML document into the Blob instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to another Engineer, got this working:

```
    var blob = new Blob([$("html").html()], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "Hello World.html");
```